# Where is the source code of Rust target components?

Tags: rust

When I run

```
rustup target install wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

it states

```
info: downloading component 'rust-std' for 'wasm32-unknown-unknown'
```

This means that prebuilt binary components are being downloaded. Where is the source code of these components?

Comment: You can find the source code of the Rust standard library [on GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/library/std).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the `rust-src` rustup component for a toolchain, which will be located in `$RUSTUP_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY/toolchains/$TOOLCHAIN/lib/rustlib/src/rust`.

This is the command:

```
rustup install rust-lang source code
```

The official source code for the Rust project is on GitHub at https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/. The standard library is currently located in the [`library/std`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/1.51.0/library/std) subdirectory, although this has changed over time.

See also:

- [Where does rustup install itself to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46739842/155423)

Comment: I got the lastest package for wasm32-unknown-unknown from [https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml](https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml,), and I found that they are all *.rlib. What should I do to compile these .rlib files by myself?

Comment: @sailing Assuming you mean "how do I compile *using* these rlibs", practically, you don't; you probably want to cross-compile. See [Can I install a library using Cargo without a Cargo.toml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36813893/155423) for steps to a technically correct answer. If you literally mean what you said, (a.k.a. how do you create them) you'd need to look at the `build-std` feature of Cargo.