# Where can I find the `std::collections` module on my computer?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am currently learning about modules and crates in Rust and I thought I could learn best by looking at a real and very commonly used module: `std::collections`. I want to be able to *view the actual files* of this package. However, I can't find it on my computer. I have looked in the folder where I created my project (and all subfolders), as well as in the `C:/users/(username)/.cargo` folder. I am running an x64 Windows 10 PC. Please let me know where I can find the `std::collections` module on my system. Thank you!

Comment: Protip: VoidTools.com/Everything

Comment: Your best bet is probably to look at the [source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/library/std/src/collections) on github, or clone the compiler repo

Comment: Std is shipped out prebuilt because it takes the nightly compiler plus a long time to build. You won't find the source code unless you put it there.

Comment: @Dai Hmm that link did not work.

Comment: @transitor Thank you very much that is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default location for components retrieved via `rustup` are in `$HOME/.rustup/` which are organized by toolchain. The source is part of the `rust-src` component and may need to be installed manually via `rustup component add rust-src`. The `std` crate can then be found in `lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std`.

So the full path for the `std::collections` module on Windows should be:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\.rustup\toolchains\<TOOLCHAIN>\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\std\src\collections
```

See also: [Where is the source code of Rust target components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66966621/where-is-the-source-code-of-rust-target-components)

Comment: Note that it will only be there if you install the `rust-src` component (`rustup component add rust-src`)

Comment: @Jmb I've added that as part of the answer. I think I always forget that because rust-analyzer [installs it automatically](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#installation).